# Gnuplot : how can I read one text string from data file?

Tags: gnuplot

I'm busy with a system for generating some plots from a big csv formatted data file.

So far, I can to do this task with gnuplot, but I like also to read some text strings from the data file, to adapt a bit and use them for labelling and/or other text boxes on the graphs. Up to now I'm not able to do this within the gnuplot command system.

**Extra requirement**: Should be able to run the code on windows.

This is my code so far:

```
# The BigDataFile.csv files starts with some lines information
# (string texts about the matrix contense). After this info block,
# all the matrix data for  the plots.

dataFileName="BigDataFile.csv"

set datafile separator "\t"     

# Read one text string at line number 'textInfoRow' from column
# number 'textInfoColumn'

textInfoRow = 5

textInfoColumn = 10

# Now try to capture the string at some location in the info block. 

set terminal unknown 

plot dataFileName every ::textRow::textRow using (textVar=stringcolumn(textColumn))  # How can we do this ????

print textVar
```

**Question**: How can we read within 'gnuplot' a single text string at a specified location in a data file?

Comment: Something went wrong with the editing of the texts, sorry for this. Next time I should do this better.....

Comment: You can still edit a question after you wrote it by clicking the edit button in the left bottom corner of your question. This time I have already helped you out and fixed your formatting.

Answer (score 1):

The issues with your code are:

1. your variables are `textInfoRow` and `textInfoColumn` and later `textRow` and `textColumn`.
2. gnuplot doesn't like to plot strings, even if the terminal is set to `unknown`.
   Simply change your expression to `(textVar=stringcolumn(textInfoColumn),0)`. It is assigning a value to the variable but plotting `0`. Check `help operators binary`. The expression `(a,b)` is serial evaluation.

Also keep in mind that gnuplot starts counting rows from `0`.

**Data:** `"BigDataFile.csv"` (make sure separators are TABs, StackOverflow converted them to SPACE)

```
# "Big" data with some header
# another header line
1.000   2.000   3.000   4.000   5.000   6.000   7.000   8.000   9.000   10.00
2.000   0.982   0.755   0.526   0.684   0.090   0.221   0.402   0.594   0.331
3.000   0.119   0.904   0.938   0.960   0.067   0.607   0.368   0.540   0.317
4.000   0.782   0.060   0.163   0.446   0.826   0.503   0.096   0.494   0.949
5.000   0.930   0.703   0.294   0.990   0.919   0.038   0.550   0.467   HERE
6.000   0.346   0.830   0.920   0.285   0.575   0.878   0.747   0.532   0.222
7.000   0.207   0.120   0.709   0.194   0.854   0.501   0.241   0.505   0.123
8.000   0.862   0.479   0.531   0.640   0.259   0.673   0.708   0.559   0.516
9.000   0.979   0.581   0.611   0.664   0.369   0.775   0.808   0.522   0.294
10.00   0.514   0.516   0.780   0.232   0.407   0.718   0.140   0.568   0.619
```

You can extract a text "cell" by the following code. I'm not sure whether this is the fastest and most efficient way, but at least it is *gnuplot-only* and therefore platform independent and should run smoothly under Linux, MacOS and Windows.

**Code:**

```
### extract one "cell" of data
reset session

dataFileName="BigDataFile.csv"

set datafile separator "\t"     
textInfoRow = 5
textInfoColumn = 10

set terminal unknown 
plot dataFileName every ::textInfoRow-1::textInfoRow-1 using (textVar=stringcolumn(textInfoColumn),0) 

print textVar 
### end of code
```

**Result:**

`HERE`

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot !! You give me a clue to the real cause of the problem. To explain my problem situation, I've changed the code a bit (see the 'textcol' mistakes ... sorry for this), and removed all the other code rubbish to.  So I removed the problem also, oeps.

Comment: The problem was : if you add pe the command 'set xrange[65:95]' before the 'plot  ....  ' function call, then the 'plot  ' code won't ran anymore.  If you 'unset' the range, then the 'plot' function call we work again without problems.  At the moment the reason isn't clear to me... I'll lookup in the documentation.

Comment: I didn't know what's before in your code. But when plotting for extracting a value like above it is actually better to do `plot [*:*][*:*] dataFileName ...`, then you will plot the full range, otherwise the range might be limited by `xrange` or `yrange`.

Comment: Thank you for the tip.  Because my complete Gnuplot code is a sequential of several plots and data manipulations, I can't reset the session somewhere in between. Now I realise that previous commands can generate function call failures further on. Also the function call error message didn't give me a tip to the cause.  I'm new with the gnuplot code, But I'm glad I can now generate very nice graphs after only one day learning .....

Comment: you don't have to do `reset session`. I'm just doing it always as a first line to have a "defined" system. As you say,... previous settings might cause strange results.